# Filter by scope in Boost.Log

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I'm using [Boost.Log](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) library. I've created a `named_scope` attribute that keeps track of where I am in the code. (I specify it by hand with `BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE("...")`.) Is it possible to create a filter (using `set_filter`) that would select only the messages from a particular scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to Andrey's latest & greatest logging [doc](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/attributes.html) :

> The scope stack is implemented as a thread-specific global storage
>   internally. There is the named_scope attribute that allows hooking
>   this stack into the logging pipeline. This attribute generates value
>   of the nested type named_scope::scope_stack which is the instance of
>   the scope stack. The attribute can be registered in the following way:
>
> logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("Scope",
>   attrs::named_scope());

Then, you should configure your *front end* sink filter to latch only your tags of interest (in the filter lambda or in your custom filter which you pass to set_filter() you can use the following in order to **extract** the scope name, assuming u work with MBCS)

```
typedef attrs::basic_named_scope< char >::value_type scope_stack;       
logging::value_extractor<char, scope_stack> S("Scope");
scope_stack s = *S(rec);
if ( s.empty() == false )
{
   const attrs::basic_named_scope_entry<char>& e = s.back(); 
   // Filter by e.scope_name
   ...
}
```

I hope it will work for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and the explanation. I've moved away from Boost.Log in the last year. Until it's included into Boost, it's too difficult to maintain. But this will be very useful if I ever switch back.